# How to get my Pi zero audio simultanusly on my hifiberry and on ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, ffmpeg, loopback

Hope you can help me.
Got a Pi Zero and Hifiberry Module playing with raspoitify. Speaker sound is fine. My goal is to have the same (raspotify) audio on a ffmpeg stream from that Pi as well. I searched the web and it seems like i needed to load the loopback stuff so I tried this:

```
modprobe snd-aloop pcm_substreams=1
```

i get this loopback devices.

```
 root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [sndrpihifiberry]: RPi-simple - snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac
                      snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac
 1 [Loopback       ]: Loopback - Loopback
                      Loopback 1
```

asound.conf

```
#pcm.!default {
# type hw card 0
#}
#ctl.!default {
# type hw card 0
#}
pcm.hifiberryMiniAmp {
    type softvol
    slave.pcm "plughw:0"
    control.name "Master"
    control.card 0
}
pcm.!default {
    type       plug
    slave.pcm  "hifiberryMiniAmp"
#slave.pcm "hw:Loopback,0,0"
}
```

any how i cant record the audio playing. It only works if i exchange the last two rows and then i am able to record the spotify stream with

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i hw:Loopback,1,0 out.wav
```

if i do the same with slave.pcm  "hifiberryMiniAmp" in that asound conf my loopback seems to be silent.

Ideas? Thanks

P.S. I wonder if its a hardware limitation i need to bypass with pulseaudio but i dont have an idea how to start on this
https://www.hifiberry.com/docs/software/mixing-different-audio-sources/

Comment: I would try "pulseaudio" after installing the "paprefs" package, See https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-multiple-simultaneous-audio-outputs-on-pulseaudio-in-linux

Comment: I'll give it a try thx, might respond here if I face any issues